# I am using dev-cpp 4.9.9.2 and it doesn't close quotes and brakets, us there a solution?

Tags: autocomplete

My editor dev-c++ doesn't automatically close brackets, quotes, double quotes, and parenthesis.. In editor options there is no way to check autocompletion as it is not present as an option

I couldn't find anyway to add it from the editor options
If there is anyway to add the iptuon from within the template olease tell me